# Cross Origin does not work - google cloud

Tags: json, google-cloud-storage

I have a problem and I have been looking for information for hours.
I wish to block access to the objects in my bucket, which can only be viewed from my website, for this I have configured the Cross Origin according to the documentation of google cloud storage.

I have this url: https://storage.googleapis.com/cros-test/480_intro%20v2_2.mp4, which has permission to be public, that same url I want it to only be visible from my web example.com

```
[
    {
      "origin": ["https://example.com"],
      "responseHeader": ["*"],
      "method": ["GET", "HEAD", "DELETE"],
      "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
    }
]
```

But it does not work for me, it's still visible to everyone

Answer (score 3):

The quick answer is that CORS does not provide authorization to Google Cloud Storage (GCS). In other words, you cannot protect GCS buckets and objects with CORS.

CORS is a security policy enforced at the browser by the browser. CORS stands for Cross-Origin Resource Sharing. The purpose of CORS is to inform the browser if resources on site B can be loaded / accessed from site A. The objective of CORS is to protect the end-user and not to protect your content.

If the user is directly accessing your URL (putting the URL in the address bar), then there is no cross origin happening. Your bucket is the origin.

Where CORS will kick in is someone else uses your object URL in their website pages for downloading objects. However, CORS is voluntary by the browser meaning that there are tools that will ignore CORS policy (curl for example). Normally, the browser will add the `Origin` header to the request which GCS then analyses. This can be faked, forged or just not specified.

For example an often overlooked issue with GCS CORS:

> Note: CORS configuration only affects requests to XML API endpoints.
> JSON API endpoints allow CORS requests, regardless of CORS settings on
> the target bucket. Requests to the endpoint storage.cloud.google.com
> do not allow CORS requests.
>
> storage.googleapis.com/your-bucket ⬅ will not have headers
>
> your-bucket.storage.googleapis.com ⬅ will have cors headers

This Google [document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin) will help explain how CORS works with GCS.

Answer (score 3):

The answer provided by John Hanley seems to be outdated. In my case I use `https://storage.googleapis.com/your-bucket` with a signed URL to access the objects from a web-app hosted on its own domain (`app.example.com`).

The fix was to make sure that the `Access-Control-Request-Headers` header field matched the `responseHeader` field in the JSON config. This meant using the following configuration:

```
[
    {
      "origin": ["https://app.example.com"],
      "method": ["GET"],
      "responseHeader": ["authorization"],
      "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
    }
]
```

By default the GCS documentation has the following config:

```
[
    {
      "origin": ["https://your-example-website.appspot.com"],
      "method": ["GET"],
      "responseHeader": ["Content-Type"],
      "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
    }
]
```

But the preflight request sent by Firefox (102) and Chrome (103) sets the header as `Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization`. Since the preflight header does not match the GCS configuration, the CORS request fails.

Comment: Thanks, you just saved my life, I have just spent 3 hours to figure out the root cause... and it was the responseHeader. This solution is working with Chrome.